# Sending message to reply-channel of http-inbound-gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a below setup with spring integration.

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="restListener"
                          request-channel="restChannel"
                          reply-channel="restResponseChannel"
                          path="/service"
                          supported-methods="POST"
                          reply-timeout="5000"
</int-http:inbound-gateway>



<int:channel id="restChannel"/>
<int:channel id="restResponseChannel"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="restChannel"
                       ref="restRequestHandler"
                       method="handleRestRequest"/>
```

I receive 2 different types of POST requests on gateway and both of them are passed to `service-activator` for processing. In one type of POST request my `service-activator` can immediately process it and reply back with a standard response. However, other type of request will be routed through different channels and processed by different processors (depending on the content). I want the output for processing both type of requests to be sent as `response` of REST call.

For first type of request I can simply do this

```
public void handleRestRequest(Message<JsonNode> postMessage) {
     if (type1) {
        // Do processing
        restResponseChannel.send(MessageBuilder
                .withPayload("{\"result\":\"success!\"}")
                .copyHeaders(postMessage.getHeaders())
                .build());
     } else {
        // send to another channel for further processing
     }

}
```

But for second type of request if I try to `send` my output to `restResponseChannel` (without headers) then I get below exception

> org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no
>   output-channel or replyChannel header available

I do not have access to original headers for second type of request. How can I send the output to `reply-channel`? (I read somewhere that gateway creates an anonymous channel to connect to the `reply-channel` and not having those headers is causing the exception, however I don't understand the underlying mechanism completely to debug this myself)

Answer (score 2):

You understand that absolutely correctly.

If you don't carry request headers, there is no `TemporaryReplyChannel` header to correlate reply with response. See `GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive()` for implementation:

```
TemporaryReplyChannel tempReplyChannel = new TemporaryReplyChannel(this.throwExceptionOnLateReply);
    requestMessage = MessageBuilder.fromMessage(requestMessage).setReplyChannel(tempReplyChannel)
            .setHeader(this.sendTimeoutHeader, null)
            .setHeader(this.receiveTimeoutHeader, null)
            .setErrorChannel(tempReplyChannel).build();

    try {
        doSend(channel, requestMessage, sendTimeout);
    }
    catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        tempReplyChannel.setSendFailed(true);
        throw ex;
    }

    Message<?> replyMessage = this.doReceive(tempReplyChannel, receiveTimeout);
```

So, if there is no that header, no possibility to accept reply. The behavior is the same like in many other messaging `replyAddress` patterns.

That `reply-channel="restResponseChannel"` is just for convenience when you don't want to consult header for the next channel or when you would like to send a reply not only to the response but to somewhere else  - publish-subscribe pattern.

You don't have choice unless carry headers anyway. One case is to use `Message` directly, another is with the `@Headers Map<String, Object>` service method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With current design it is not possible for me to carry headers around. I will have to find another way or might have to change design!

Comment: I still don't understand the point of having `reply-channel` if we can't send messages to it? can you please explain?

Comment: We need only `replyChannel` header to correlate reply with the request. The `reply-channel` attribute is only for convenience. Underneath there is a bridging from the `reply-channel` to the `replyChannel` header. If you would like to send reply to the waiting request, you don't have choice unless to store somewhere `replyChannel` header. The same you can't do with simple JMS, if you don't store `replyTo` for the future use.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My temporary solution is to have a separate poll-able channel where I store `replyChannel` header for every incoming rest request. Then at later point I simply get those headers from that channel and post a message to `reply-channel` with those headers. If it works without any issues I will add it as an answer to this question (in case someone needs it in future)